# Chemical Potential in the Fluorescent Molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, fluorescence

I'm reading this [paper](https://www.osapublishing.org/josa/abstract.cfm?uri=josa-70-11-1362), which states that the chemical potential $\mu$ is determined by the steady-state balance of up and down transitions in a fluorescent molecule. I am happy with this interpretation. But what I don't know how to verify is the next statement:

*"For a high-quantum-efficiency fluorescent molecule illuminated at the earth surface, $\mu$ is usually $0.6$ or $0.7$ times $h\nu$ at the centre of the absorption band".*

How would I show that $\mu$ is usually $0.6$ or $0.7$ times $h\nu$ at the centre of the absorption band?

Comment: This would seem to be due to the $T\Delta S$ caused by the Stokes shift that leads to heat not photons, but it's not clear why it has these values. You will have to test some values of frequency shift.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not quite sure I understand. So, a portion of the absorption leads to heat - but surely at high efficiency, this would be diminished?

Comment: There can still be a wavelength shift between absorption and emission even if the efficiency is high.  $v=0\to 1$ is different in wavelength $v=1\to 0$ due to relaxation in excited state vs ground state  due to differing interactions with solvent caused by changed electron distribution. The mean absorption and mean emission will always have a shift .